# Add result set of an sql query to email Body in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add the output of an SQL (invoke-sqlcmd) query to the body of an email sent by my Powershell script.

The sql query works fine and the email works fine. I just can't figure out how to add the results to the body of the email.

```
function SendEmail
{

invoke-sqlcmd -Query "SELECT 'Sql {Select} Query" | format-table 

$MsgBody = "All files have been downloaded correctly for " + $Date
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($EmailSMTPServer)
$credentials=new-object system.net.networkcredential("MailServer","Password")
$smtp.credentials=$credentials.getcredential($smtpserver,"25","basic")
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject,$MsgBody)
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function SendEmail
{

$Query=invoke-sqlcmd -Query "SELECT 'Sql {Select} Query" | out-string 

$MsgBody = "All files have been downloaded correctly for " + $Date + "`n"
$MsgBody += $Query

$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($EmailSMTPServer)
$credentials=new-object system.net.networkcredential("MailServer","Password")
$smtp.credentials=$credentials.getcredential($smtpserver,"25","basic")
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject,$MsgBody)
}
```

The above seems to have done the trick. I replaced Format-table with out-string.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question here!  your switch to using out-string helped me in the exact same way.